# Grub2 loopback command out of memory

Tags: linux, grub2

I have an asus rog strix g614 with 32gb ram. I installed fedora 38, and with it grub version 2.06. I made an ext4 partition where I put an image file of Ubuntu so to load it with Grub. I have this error:

```
error: ../../grub-core/kern/mm.c552:out of memory.
```

Entering the command line I can see that this error is generated by the loopback command, that i can manually call with

```
grub> loopback loop (hd0,4)/ubuntu-23.iso
```

I tried different images, Ubuntu ~4gb, Fedora ~2gb with no success. I was able to mount though puppy linux ~400mb, with the command

```
grub> loopback loop (hd0,4)/fossapup64-9.5.iso
```

so i guess the problem looks like the size of the image.

How to solve the issue?

Comment: Examples of grub loop mount stanzas. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1269462/bios-uefi-template-image-for-booting-iso-files & https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Multiboot_USB_drive#GParted_Live & https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/ISOBoot
more examples
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/ISOBoot/Examples Getting partition/path & parameters for various ISO are often biggest issues. You can look into ISO for its grub parameters.

Comment: Thanks, but I was aware of the content of those links. I'm not sure what parameters you are referring to, the error was isolated running the 'loopback' command on the command line (At grub start, press c to enter command line). With command line you can execute step by step the commands executed by the custom menu entry.

Comment: As a workaround, you could copy the files you're trying to access through loopback (usually the kernel + initramfs only) and access them directly. That way you don't need loopback in your bootloader at all.